# Python dict: there a speed difference between matching a numeric key over a word in python?

Tags: python, mysql

In a Python dict of 50 items would there be any known noticeable speed difference in matching an integer key (2 digits) to find a string value VERSUS matching a string key (5 - 10+ letters) to find an integer value over a large number of loops  (100,000+)?

As a minor bonus; is there any benefit to performing an activity like this in MYSQL versus Python if you're able to?

Comment: Why don't you measure it yourself. `timeit` is your friend.

Comment: Dictionary lookups are hash maps from key -> value.  The retrieval time should be `O(1)`.

Comment: @g.d.d.c - could you elaborate on the last part just a little bit?

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac Cool beans! Didn't know that existed. I figured I'd probably end up testing it, but I wasn't sure if any part of this was common knowledge or not. Such as, "of course it's faster with the numbers, there are less digits/bytes/etc" or anything of that nature.

Comment: `O(1)` means that the retrieval of an individual key from a dictionary should not vary with the size the dictionary.  The _work_ done to retrieve any particular value is constant - hash the key, check buckets, identify collisions, return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micro-benchmarking language
features is a useful exercise, but you have to take it with
a grain of salt. It's hard to do
benchmarks in accurate and meaningful ways, and generally
what people care about are total performance, not individual feature
performance.

I find using a "test harness" makes it easier to run
differnet alternatives in a comparable way.

For dictionary lookup, here's an example using the [benchmark](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/benchmark) module from PyPI.
100
randomized runs, setting up `dict`s of N=50 items
each--either `int` keys and `str` values or the
reverse, then trying both the `try`/`except`s
and `get` access paradigms. Here's the code:

```
import benchmark
from random import choice, randint
import string

def str_key(length=8, alphabet=string.ascii_letters):
    return ''.join(choice(alphabet) for _ in xrange(length))

def int_key(min=10, max=99):
    return randint(min, max)

class Benchmark_DictLookup(benchmark.Benchmark):

    each = 100 # allows for differing number of runs

    def setUp(self):
        # Only using setUp in order to subclass later
        # Can also specify tearDown, eachSetUp, and eachTearDown
        self.size = 1000000
        self.n = 50
        self.intdict = { int_key():str_key() for _ in xrange(self.n) }
        self.strdict = { str_key():int_key() for _ in xrange(self.n) }
        self.intkeys = [ int_key() for _ in xrange(self.size) ]
        self.strkeys = [ str_key() for _ in xrange(self.size) ]

    def test_int_lookup(self):
        d = self.intdict
        for key in self.intkeys:
            try:
                d[key]
            except KeyError:
                pass

    def test_int_lookup_get(self):
        d = self.intdict
        for key in self.intkeys:
            d.get(key, None)

    def test_str_lookup(self):
        d = self.strdict
        for key in self.strkeys:
            try:
                d[key]
            except KeyError:
                pass

    def test_str_lookup_get(self):
        d = self.strdict
        for key in self.strkeys:
            d.get(key, None)


class Benchmark_Hashing(benchmark.Benchmark):

    each = 100 # allows for differing number of runs

    def setUp(self):
        # Only using setUp in order to subclass later
        # Can also specify tearDown, eachSetUp, and eachTearDown
        self.size = 100000
        self.intkeys = [ int_key() for _ in xrange(self.size) ]
        self.strkeys = [ str_key() for _ in xrange(self.size) ]


    def test_int_hash(self):
        for key in self.intkeys:
            id(key)

    def test_str_hash(self):
        for key in self.strkeys:
            id(key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    benchmark.main(format="markdown", numberFormat="%.4g")
```

And the results:

```
$ python dictspeed.py

Benchmark Report
================

Benchmark DictLookup
--------------------

          name | rank | runs |   mean |      sd | timesBaseline
---------------|------|------|--------|---------|--------------
int lookup get |    1 |  100 | 0.1756 | 0.01619 |           1.0
str lookup get |    2 |  100 | 0.1859 | 0.01477 | 1.05832996073
    int lookup |    3 |  100 | 0.5236 | 0.03935 | 2.98143047487
    str lookup |    4 |  100 | 0.8168 | 0.04961 | 4.65108861267

Benchmark Hashing
-----------------

    name | rank | runs |     mean |        sd | timesBaseline
---------|------|------|----------|-----------|--------------
int hash |    1 |  100 | 0.008738 |  0.000489 |           1.0
str hash |    2 |  100 | 0.008925 | 0.0002952 | 1.02137781609

Each of the above 600 runs were run in random, non-consecutive order by
`benchmark` v0.1.5 (http://jspi.es/benchmark) with Python 2.7.5
Darwin-13.4.0-x86_64 on 2014-10-28 19:23:01.
```

Conclusion: String lookup in dictionaries is not that much more expensive than integer lookup. **BUT** the supposedly Pythonic "ask forgiveness not permission" paradigm takes *much* longer than simply using the `get` method call. Also, hashing a string (at least of size 8) is not much more expensive than hashing an integer.

But then things get even more interesting if you run on a different implementation, like PyPy:

```
$ pypy dictspeed.py

Benchmark Report
================

Benchmark DictLookup
--------------------

          name | rank | runs |    mean |        sd | timesBaseline
---------------|------|------|---------|-----------|--------------
int lookup get |    1 |  100 | 0.01538 | 0.0004682 |           1.0
str lookup get |    2 |  100 | 0.01993 |  0.001117 |   1.295460397
    str lookup |    3 |  100 |  0.0203 |  0.001566 | 1.31997704025
    int lookup |    4 |  100 | 0.02316 |  0.001056 | 1.50543635375

Benchmark Hashing
-----------------

    name | rank | runs |      mean |        sd | timesBaseline
---------|------|------|-----------|-----------|--------------
str hash |    1 |  100 | 0.0005657 | 0.0001609 |           1.0
int hash |    2 |  100 |  0.006066 | 0.0005283 |  10.724346492

Each of the above 600 runs were run in random, non-consecutive order by
`benchmark` v0.1.5 (http://jspi.es/benchmark) with Python 2.7.8
Darwin-13.4.0-x86_64 on 2014-10-28 19:23:57.
```

PyPy is about 11x faster, best case, but the ratios are much different. PyPy doesn't suffer the significant exception-handling cost that CPython does. And, hashing an integer is 10x *slower* than hashing a string. How about that for an unexpected result?

I would have tried Python 3, but `benchmark` didn't install well there. I also tried increasing the string length to 50. It didn't markedly change the results, the ratios, or the conclusions.

Overall, hashing and lookups are so fast that, unless you have to do them by the millions or billions, or have extraordinarily long keys, or some other unusual circumstance, developers generally needn't be concerned about their micro-performance.

Comment: If you think anyone would suggest it's more Pythonic to use `try..except` instead of `get()`, you are either misunderstanding or listening to the wrong people. Yes, EAFP is encouraged over LBYL, but `get()` isn't an example of LBYL.

Comment: So, if I'm reading this correctly, if I were to make 160k lookups of value (by str key), the lookups themselves would take a total of approximately 4.6 minutes (vs 4.95 minutes), and a mere 24 seconds in PyPy. I'd never really looked at PyPy - holy cow is that much faster. Although, still low numbers regardless.

Thank you for running the test and including the code - now I'll be sure to run my own tests in the future. Great job @Jonathan Eunice

Comment: @JohnY I agree it's a bad idea, but yes I have seen multiple tutorials and discussions over the years ([example](http://www.endmemo.com/program/python/keyerror.php)) that recommend exception handling to the `key in d` or `d.get(key, None)` approaches. For a few years, it seemed to be a pretty religious/contentious issue. `get` is sufficiently LBYL, in that it guards against unhappy exceptional outcomes. If you like calling only the `key in d` conditional LBYL, then `get` is more Leap But Don't Fail.

Comment: @JonathanEunice: If there is such a thing as "Leap But Don't Fail" then `try..except` also meets that definition! I'd say it's more useful to think of `get()` as an efficient `try..except`. But I'm fine with putting `get()` into a different category altogether than the `try` or `in`. The point is that Python is not about picking one dichotomy at a time and always choosing one end of that dichotomy over the other. It's about simultaneously balancing *many* competing concerns and deftly navigating them all (see the Zen).

Comment: @JonathanEunice: `get()` is Pythonic because it gives you both better readability and practicality than either of the other approaches, if indeed your use case fits what `get()` provides.

Comment: @Tim Um...4 or 5 minutes?! No. Much, *much* less. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jonathaneunice/fed67abca4150cf85d35) for details, but the worst case is under 0.13 seconds for 160k lookups.  With `get` it's less than 0.03 seconds. In 4.65 minutes, it will do ~1.7 billion (with a B) lookups (or over 9 billion in PyPy).

Comment: The benchmark module not supporting Python 3 seemed like a problem. So I fixed it. I submitted the update for inclusion in the mainline, but in the meanwhile, it's available [on github](https://github.com/jonathaneunice/benchmark)

Comment: Yikes! I used some terrible code while trying to test that previously. Thank you for clearing that up. 

I now understand your original code better - it does runs of 1 million lookups.